# Angular 1.3 : input field cleared with $parsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Just updated to Angular 1.3 and my "capitalize" directive does not works as previously.

Here is my directive :

```
.directive('capitalize', function(){
return {
    restrict :'A',
    require:'ngModel',
    link : function(scope, elt, attrs, modelCtrl){

        modelCtrl.$parsers.push( function(value){
            var up = value.toUpperCase();

            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(up);
            modelCtrl.$render();
            return up;
        })


    }
}
```

})

When I use it on an input field validated with a ng-maxlength directive, the behavior is quite strange ...

```
<input capitalize ng-model="c.myField1" ng-maxlength="3" name="myField1" />
```

If I enter more than 3 characters, the input field is cleared. Why ?

I cannot understand why, would you like to help me to solve this issue ?

Obviously, it was ok before I updated from 1.3rc1.

Here is a fiddle example : http://fiddle.jshell.net/dctf1p8e/4/

Comment: I would suggest to just remove `ng-maxlength` and move this logic to the parser, like this: `return up.substring(0, 6)`;

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I migrated.  I'm following this trail:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9295

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/9681

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9986

Basically, my guess is that there is something off with the `$render` side of things when used in conjunction with `viewValue` or `setViewValue`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a legitimate bug in the $render() call that checks if the modelValue is empty before calling .val() (see: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9156)

Until this is fixed you could just add `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` wherever your directive is being appended or construct a custom directive which achieves the same result (probably unnecessary considering a fix is presumably in the works).

I would suggest periodically checking up on the status of (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9156) if you're concerned about the unnecessary use of the ng-model-options attribute.